# What is a Quantum Network Bridge

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm looking over parts of the [AE Mod](http://ae-mod.info/) I haven't experimented with yet and I can't help but notice the interesting looking [Quantum Network Bridge](http://ae-mod.info/ME-Quantum-Network-Bridge/). I'm reading it's description but my stupid bone is acting up and I'm not entirely sure I understand the information exactly. I *think* this is to bridge two networks, just like in real life. Am I correct? Is this structure's purpose to connect two otherwise unconnected networks so they can access each-other's inventory and crafting system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Quantum Network Bridge](http://ae-mod.info/ME-Quantum-Network-Bridge/) will allow a network to cross dimensions and large gaps.

However, only 1 controller must exist on the network, or if there is a controller on the other side then the network won't work anymore. (both sides become a single network)

To create one surround a [Quantum Link Chamber](http://ae-mod.info/Quantum-Link-Chamber/) with 8 [Quantum Field Rings](http://ae-mod.info/Quantum-Field-Ring/) and put a [Quantum Entangled Singularity](http://ae-mod.info/Quantum-Entangled-Singularity/) in [Quantum Link Chamber](http://ae-mod.info/Quantum-Link-Chamber/)

You need to connect ME cable to the field ring to connect it to the network and you need to power the ring directly with 200 units/t (40 mj/t, 100 eu/t, 4 kj/t) of energy.

Do this on both sides (with matching singularities) and then the networks should act as one single network.